# 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech, sapi

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.Speech.dll
>
> Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {49428A60-C997-4D0E-9808-9E326C178D58} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I am following [this sample from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378426(v=office.14).aspx) for Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Microsoft.Speech;
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));                        ======>>**ERROR** 
            sre.SetInputToWaveFile(@"c:\Test\Colors.wav");
            Choices colors = new Choices();
            colors.Add(new string[] { "red", "green", "blue" });

            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(colors);

            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
            sre.LoadGrammar(g);

            // Register a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
            sre.SpeechRecognized +=
              new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);

            // Start recognition.
            sre.Recognize();

            sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
        
        }

        private void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Speech recognized: " + e.Result.Text);
        }

       
    }
}
```

Comment: To save one having to paste your code into a project, add necessary references etcetera just to get started helping you, _on what line_ does the exception occur?

Comment: it works when i change project properties to run in X64

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: open project properties->Build->Platform Target->change it to X 64 from Any CPU

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you only installed the 64-bit version of the [Speech Platform Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16789), and not the 32-bit version.

Comment: Sure, i confirm, had same problem, solved installing Speech Platform Runtime 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to install the [Microsoft Speech Platform **Runtime**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225) as well. Although I already had the Speech SDK and the Kinect SDK installed.